# Puppet - How to achieve ordering/sequencing in Puppet when there are dependencies between nodes

Tags: puppet

I am setting up an hypothetical environment with two nodes, where one node is required to host database server while the other node is required to host a service that makes use of the database server. I am using Puppet for configuration management of the environment. The following is the relevant snippet from the site.pp

```
node 'db-server' {
   role::db_server #This is required to be deployed before service.
}
node 'service' {
   role::service #This requires database server to be up and running.
}
```

What are different ways to achieve ordering/sequencing in Puppet when there are dependencies between nodes. For now, I am relying on executing 'Puppet apply' command in phases. I execute 'Puppet apply' first on db-server node and then on service node.

I am looking for different ways and some pointers on how to achieve ordering/sequencing in Puppet when there are dependencies between nodes.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Puppet is idempotent, run two or more `puppet apply / puppet agent -t` will be no impact for your system. Get the fail in first run, then after database server is ready, your service server will be fine.

Comment: Is there a centralized PuppetDB? Achieving orchestration without a central registry will be all the more difficult.

Comment: @FelixFrank No, there is not centralized PuppetDB. Are you suggesting using PuppetDB and exported resources?

Comment: @AnandPatel yes, that, or you might even get away with querying fact values from other nodes. There is also a fascinating [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/garethr/service-discovery-and-configuration-management) about using Service Discovery with Consul through Hiera.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinating puppet runs across multiple machines is easiest by controlling when puppet runs yourself, much like you are doing now.

That doesn't mean it needs to be manual though! You can script running puppet with ssh, or if you want to do it in the more "puppet" way you can use [mcollective to coordinate puppet runs](https://www.devco.net/archives/2013/02/03/managing-puppet-using-mcollective.php). You are still going to be telling puppet when to run, but mcollective makes it easier to script deployments across a larger environment (say if you have multiple database servers and web servers).